# How to find out which value is the smallest between outputs in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, comparison

For example :

```
S1=3
S2=6
S3=10
```

I want to determine which S# is the smallest.

I tried the following :

```
s=[S1 S2 S3] 

Low=min(s)
```

However this only shows **what** is the smallest output, but doesn't identify **which one** of the S's is the smallest. What code allows me to do that ?

Also, can I identify which array in **s** is the smallest? (1st 2nd or 3rd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = [2 4 5 1]
[V I] = min(x)
```

I returns the index.